# Why does the black hole's matter ring in the image released on April 10th seem to lack blue/red shift?

Tags: black-holes, doppler-effect, redshift

If the matter around a black hole is spinning around it at nearly the speed of light, then the blue/red shift on each side should be quite visible (even though we're watching at an angle). But in this image I fail to notice any.
[image: First ever picture of a black hole]

Comment: Answer (linked): it's not a color image.  The bright side is the side that's approaching us.

Comment: It is a monochromatic image.